# WARNING: python binary not found on PATH

Tags: python, zsh

Whenever I launch iTerm2 w/zsh i get the following message:

```
WARNING: python binary not found on PATH.
zsh-autoswitch-virtualenv plugin will be disabled.
```

If i type this i get the following path:

```
~ ❯ echo $PATH                                                 

/Users/macm1/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/macm1/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/macm1/Library/Python/3.8/bin:/Users/macm1/.pyenv/bin:/Users/macm1/.pyenv/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/macm1/.fig/bin:/Users/macm1/.local/bin:/Users/macm1/.local/bin:/Users/macm1/.local/bin
```

Also:

```
~ ❯ which python3                                              
/Users/macm1/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

```
~ ❯ python --version                                           
Python 3.9.7
```

```
~ ❯ ls -l /usr/bin/python                                      
"/usr/bin/python": No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

In my zsh shell i have the following:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/macm1/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH

 # Created by `pipx`
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/macm1/.local/bin"

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$('/Users/macm1/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/macm1/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/macm1/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/macm1/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

Can anyone assist with this?

Comment: _Probably_ the error comes from within the `__conda_setup` assignment; can you please show us your troubleshooting efforts? Adding `echo 'checkpoint 1' >&2` just before the call and a similar `checkpoint 2` shortly after should help pinpoint this. (You can't put it immediately after because that will reset the value of `$?`. Tangentially, see also [Why is testing ”$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern))

Comment: My guess is that some of the tools you use for initializing zsh, is trying to invoke Python as `python` instead of as `python3`.

Comment: Obviously you have defined something named `python`, but it is either not an executable, or if it is one, it is not located in `/usr/bin`. To find more about what your _python_ really is, enter `type -a python`

Comment: Can you please add your _entire_ `.zshrc` file to your question? The message you posted clearly states your are using the `zsh-autoswitch-virtualenv` plugin, yet it’s not visible anywhere in the code that you shared.

Comment: @marlonrichert the .zshrc is too long to post but the plugin appears in the plugins section ''' plugins=(
  zsh-history-enquirer
  zsh-aliases-exa
 git
 z
 github
  gitcd
 fast-syntax-highlighting
 zsh-autosuggestions
  auto-color-ls
  mistory
  update-plugin
  vscode
  autoswitch_virtualenv $plugins
)
'''

Comment: In that case, try commenting out lines from your `.zshrc` file until you find what’s actually causing the problem.

Comment: You need to update your question with a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

so, the problem is that "**zsh-autoswitch-virtualenv plugin**" is checking for ***python*** on ur system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUbUD.png)

but you may have installed ***python3***.

so to fix this,
go to ur `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` file with vim or nano.

the add this lines at the top:

```
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```